# MySql difference between two timestamps in days?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

How can I get the difference between two timestamps in days? Should I be using a datetime column for this?

---

I switched my column to datetime. Simple subtraction doesn't seem to give me a result in days.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), last_confirmation_attempt, NOW() - last_confirmation_attempt AS diff  FROM DateClubs HAVING diff IS NOT NULL ;
+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
| NOW()               | last_confirmation_attempt | diff            |
+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
| 2010-03-30 10:52:31 | 2010-03-16 10:41:47       | 14001084.000000 |
+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't think `diff` is in seconds, because when I divide `diff` by number of seconds in a day ( 86,400 ), I don't get a sensical answer:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), last_confirmation_attempt, ( NOW() - last_confirmation_attempt) / 86400 AS diff  FROM DateClubs HAVING diff IS NOT NULL ;
+---------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
| NOW()               | last_confirmation_attempt | diff           |
+---------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
| 2010-03-30 10:58:58 | 2010-03-16 10:41:47       | 162.0568402778 |
+---------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What datatype are your columns/values at the moment?

Comment: I was using timestamps, but I just changed one column to datetime.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you're happy to ignore the time portion in the columns, [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) will give you the difference you're looking for in days.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36') AS days;
+------+
| days |
+------+
|   17 |
+------+
```

Comment: I was also googling for how to find the difference between the current date, so let it be here: `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '2015-04-18')`.

Answer (score 13):

I know is quite old, but I'll say just for the sake of it - I was looking for the same problem and got here, but I needed the difference in days.

I used `SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE2))/60/60/24`
Unix_timestamp returns the difference in seconds, and then I just divide into minutes(seconds/60), hours(minutes/60), days(hours/24).

Comment: Does this properly handle leap years?

Comment: Yes, because the timestamp handles the leap years. The timestamp difference returns the difference between two dates in seconds. If you divide until day, you are fine (every single day every year has the same amount of seconds).

Comment: @Enrico - Not true. Some days have an extra second or two seconds depending on the year. Those occur on either midnight of June 30th or midnight of December 31st. They are leap seconds which adjust for the drift between mean solar day seconds versus the atomic clock second. If you check UNIX and SQL calculators, they will allow for a 62 second minute which means seconds values can range from 0 to 61 inclusive. The adjustment can be negative by two seconds also, but that has never occurred since the drift is always towards needing positive leap seconds. The standard allows for up to 2 seconds.

Comment: @Jim I have never had to deal with that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Enrico - another thing to think about is the presence of 23 and 25 hour days in some civil time systems. UTC doesn't ever have that, but North America's and most of Europe's (at the very least) civil time systems also have 23 and 25 hour days whenever clocks are adjusted to or from so-called summer or daylight-savings time. The rules for when a 23 or 25 hour day will occur can be complex. UNIX and SQL time systems have this built in. UTC never observes a 23 or 25 hour day but it still has the aforementioned leap seconds.

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE t (d1 timestamp, d2 timestamp);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 05:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 00:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-04-01 13:00:00');

SELECT d2, d1, DATEDIFF(d2, d1) AS diff FROM t;

+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| d2                  | d1                  | diff |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 2010-03-30 05:00:00 | 2010-03-11 12:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-11 12:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-11 00:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-10 12:00:00 |   20 |
| 2010-04-01 13:00:00 | 2010-03-10 12:00:00 |   22 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to return in full TIMESTAMP format than try it: -

```
 SELECT TIMEDIFF(`call_end_time`, `call_start_time`) as diff from tablename;
```

return like

```
     diff
     - - -
    00:05:15
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need the difference in days accounting up to the second:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2010-09-21 21:40:36','2010-10-08 18:23:13')/86400 AS diff
```

It will return
    `diff`
    `16.8629`

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT DATEDIFF( now(), '2013-06-20' );`

> here datediff takes two arguments 'upto-date', 'from-date'
>
> What i have done is, using now() function, i can get no. of days since 20-june-2013 till today.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATEDIFF(max_date, min_date) as days from my table.
This works even if the col `max_date` and `min_date` are in string data types.

Answer (score 0):

Further elaborating upon the answer given by @DanielVassallo and providing an alternate method using `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function instead of the `DATEDIFF()` function used by @DanielVassallo -

```
CREATE TABLE t (d1 timestamp, d2 timestamp);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 05:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-11 00:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-04-01 13:00:00');

SELECT d1, d2, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, d1, d2) AS diff FROM t;

+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| d1                  | d2                  | diff |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 2010-03-11 12:00:00 | 2010-03-30 05:00:00 |   18 |
| 2010-03-11 12:00:00 | 2010-03-30 13:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-11 00:00:00 | 2010-03-30 13:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-10 12:00:00 | 2010-03-30 13:00:00 |   20 |
| 2010-03-10 12:00:00 | 2010-04-01 13:00:00 |   22 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```