# Difference between two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

How to calculate the difference between two dates, in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh: mm: ss` and to get the result in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @didxga: Beware: (end - start) does NOT return a seconds difference between datetime values. It returns a number that is the difference between decimal numbers that look like yyyymmddhhmmss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two timestamps in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528219/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-seconds)

Answer (score 404, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01');
-- result: 22:00:59, the difference in HH:MM:SS format


SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00'); 
-- result: 79259  the difference in seconds
```

So, you can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` for your purpose.

Comment: What does "the difference in seconds for days" mean exactly? I don't understand why multiplying the result of `TIMEDIFF` by `24*60*60` is not equal to the result of `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

Comment: This solution worked for me! But in my case, I´d like to perform the TIMESTAMPDIFF in DAY, but not considering the weekends (sat/sun). I mean, only week days difference... Is it possible in a simple way? If not, I appologize for the inconvenience then I´ll look for another solution. TKs.

Comment: TIMEDIFF in the example is incorrect as that is not the number of seconds between those two days.  TIMEDIFF returns a TIME value, which has hours, minutes and seconds of the difference.  Multiplying it will not yield a useful answer.  Use TIMESTAMPDIFF.

Comment: Interesting that `TIMEDIFF()` expects the beginning and ending time arguments to be in the opposite order than is expected by `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`.

Comment: Note: When using TIMEDIFF function, the time value can range from "-838:59:59" to "838:59:59".

https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_timediff.asp

Comment: I think there are several ways of solving this;

`ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, updated_at, NOW()) / (1)) AS 'Date',` gives you the time differences in hours

`ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, updated_at, NOW()) / (1)) AS 'Date',` gives you the time differences in seconds.

`ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, updated_at, NOW()) / (60 * 60)) AS 'Date',` gives you the time differences in hours.

Answer (score 48):

If you are working with DATE columns (or can cast them as date columns), try DATEDIFF() and then multiply by 24 hours, 60 min, 60 secs (since DATEDIFF returns diff in days).  From MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

for example:

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30 00:00:00') * 24*60*60
```

Comment: I dont think this work. `DATEDIFF` doesnt return fractions.

Answer (score 44):

Get the date difference in days using DATEDIFF

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-10-08 18:23:13', '2010-09-21 21:40:36') AS days;
+------+
| days |
+------+
|   17 |
+------+
```

**OR**

Refer the below link
[MySql difference between two timestamps in days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546053/mysql-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-days)

Comment: dear, its perfect for above question, but i want some modification with same query so could please help me that how can is achive that. here i want to compare end result with my value, like ``SELECT * FROM table where datediff(today,databasedate) as days =3;`` something like this

Comment: @SoorajAbbasi Replying to an old comment, but for reference for anyone in the future: This will only check for if the date was exactly 3 days - you could do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(database_date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),'2013-05-15 10:23:23')
   calculates difference in hour.(for days--> you have to define day replacing hour
SELECT DATEDIFF('2012-2-2','2012-2-1')

SELECT TO_DAYS ('2012-2-2')-TO_DAYS('2012-2-1')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
unix_timestamp('2007-12-30 00:00:00') - 
unix_timestamp('2007-11-30 00:00:00');
```

Comment: unix_timestamp - a standard way of timing in the Unix-like systems. Represents a 32-bit integer, indicating how many seconds have passed since 01/01/1970 00:00:00. Ie a lower limit. The upper boundary is limited to 2,106 a year, but due to frequent programs does not operate with this value (instead of an unsigned integer using signed integer) is considered the upper limit in 2038.

Comment: + when passing through the DST is incorrectly deducted / added

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add where clause with DATEDIFF then it is also possible to add where clause or condition.
Take a look of following example.

```
select DATEDIFF(now(), '2022-08-12 17:55:51.000000') from properties p WHERE p.property_name = 'KEY';
```

Result : 6

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2018-01-19 14:17:15','2018-01-20 14:17:15');
```

Second approach

`SELECT ( DATEDIFF('1993-02-20','1993-02-19')*( 24*60*60) )AS 'seccond';`

```
CURRENT_TIME() --this will return current Date
DATEDIFF('','') --this function will return  DAYS and in 1 day there are 24hh 60mm 60sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use TIMEDIFF function

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2000:01:01 00:00:00.000001');
'-00:00:00.000001'
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001' , '2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002');
 '46:58:57.999999'
```

Comment: TC wants to get results value in seconds or milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes the difference between two dates and shows it in a date format yyyy-mm-dd. All you need is to execute the code below and then use the function. After executing you can use it like this

```
SELECT datedifference(date1, date2)
FROM ....
.
.
.
.


DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION datedifference(date1 DATE, date2 DATE) RETURNS DATE
NO SQL

BEGIN
    DECLARE dif DATE;
    IF DATEDIFF(date1, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date1),'-', MONTH(date1), '-', DAY(date2)))) < 0    THEN
                SET dif=DATE_FORMAT(
                                        CONCAT(
                                            PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(date1, '%y%m'),date_format(date2, '%y%m'))DIV 12 , 
                                            '-',
                                            PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(date1, '%y%m'),date_format(date2, '%y%m'))% 12 , 
                                            '-',
                                            DATEDIFF(date1, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date1),'-', MONTH(DATE_SUB(date1, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), '-', DAY(date2))))),
                                        '%Y-%m-%d');
    ELSEIF DATEDIFF(date1, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date1),'-', MONTH(date1), '-', DAY(date2)))) < DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(date1, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))) THEN
                SET dif=DATE_FORMAT(
                                        CONCAT(
                                            PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(date1, '%y%m'),date_format(date2, '%y%m'))DIV 12 , 
                                            '-',
                                            PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(date1, '%y%m'),date_format(date2, '%y%m'))% 12 , 
                                            '-',
                                            DATEDIFF(date1, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date1),'-', MONTH(date1), '-', DAY(date2))))),
                                        '%Y-%m-%d');
    ELSE
                SET dif=DATE_FORMAT(
                                        CONCAT(
                                            PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(date1, '%y%m'),date_format(date2, '%y%m'))DIV 12 , 
                                            '-',
                                            PERIOD_DIFF(date_format(date1, '%y%m'),date_format(date2, '%y%m'))% 12 , 
                                            '-',
                                            DATEDIFF(date1, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(date1),'-', MONTH(date1), '-', DAY(date2))))),
                                        '%Y-%m-%d');
    END IF;

RETURN dif;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+(to_date( '31-MAY-2012 12:25', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') 
                             - to_date( '31-MAY-2012 10:37', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')), 
        'HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

> -- result : 01:48:00

OK it's not quite what the OP asked, but it's what I wanted to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code calculate difference between two dates in yyyy MM dd format.

```
declare @StartDate datetime 
declare @EndDate datetime

declare @years int
declare @months int 
declare @days int

--NOTE: date of birth must be smaller than As on date, 
--else it could produce wrong results
set @StartDate = '2013-12-30' --birthdate
set @EndDate  = Getdate()            --current datetime

--calculate years
select @years = datediff(year,@StartDate,@EndDate)

--calculate months if it's value is negative then it 
--indicates after __ months; __ years will be complete
--To resolve this, we have taken a flag @MonthOverflow...
declare @monthOverflow int
select @monthOverflow = case when datediff(month,@StartDate,@EndDate) - 
  ( datediff(year,@StartDate,@EndDate) * 12) <0 then -1 else 1 end
--decrease year by 1 if months are Overflowed
select @Years = case when @monthOverflow < 0 then @years-1 else @years end
select @months =  datediff(month,@StartDate,@EndDate) - (@years * 12) 

--as we do for month overflow criteria for days and hours 
--& minutes logic will followed same way
declare @LastdayOfMonth int
select @LastdayOfMonth =  datepart(d,DATEADD
    (s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@EndDate)+1,0)))

select @days = case when @monthOverflow<0 and 
    DAY(@StartDate)> DAY(@EndDate) 
then @LastdayOfMonth + 
  (datepart(d,@EndDate) - datepart(d,@StartDate) ) - 1  
      else datepart(d,@EndDate) - datepart(d,@StartDate) end 


select
 @Months=case when @days < 0 or DAY(@StartDate)> DAY(@EndDate) then @Months-1 else @Months end

Declare @lastdayAsOnDate int;
set @lastdayAsOnDate = datepart(d,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@EndDate),0)));
Declare @lastdayBirthdate int;
set @lastdayBirthdate =  datepart(d,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+1,0)));

if (@Days < 0) 
(
    select @Days = case when( @lastdayBirthdate > @lastdayAsOnDate) then
        @lastdayBirthdate + @Days
    else
        @lastdayAsOnDate + @Days
    end
)
print  convert(varchar,@years)   + ' year(s),   '  +
       convert(varchar,@months)  + ' month(s),   ' +
       convert(varchar,@days)    + ' day(s)   '
```

Comment: Why not simply use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you've a date stored in text field as string you can implement this code it will fetch the list of past number of days a week, a month or a year sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY

//This is for a month

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY

//This is for a week
```

%d%m%Y is your date format

This query display the record between the days you set there like: Below from last 7 days and Above from last 14 days so it would be your last week record to be display same concept is for month or year. Whatever value you're providing in below date like: below from 7-days so the other value would be its double as 14 days. What we are saying here get all records above from last 14 days and below from last 7 days. This is a week record you can change value to 30-60 days for a month and also for a year.

Thank You Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

You would simply do this:

```
SELECT (end_time - start_time) FROM t; -- return in Millisecond
SELECT (end_time - start_time)/1000 FROM t; -- return in Second
```

Comment: Beware: (end - start) does NOT return a seconds difference between datetime values. It returns a number that is the difference between decimal numbers that look like yyyymmddhhmmss.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just

Select Sum(Date1 - Date2) from table

date1 and date2 are datetime

Comment: This doesn't return the date difference in seconds, instead it returns the difference between decimal numbers that look like yyyymmddhhmmss.  So, this doesn't solve OP's question.  The same thing is mentioned in the comment on the question as well.