# how to calculate time difference between two dates - MySql

Tags: mysql

```
code   | user_id   | register_date | time_difference
-------+-----------+---------------+----------------
AiK4JJ | kcy2000ok | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:41
unBG1D | gktoql    | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:35
vzqeWU | gktoql    | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:32
vvkOSd | gktoql    | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:32
uwhbGt | ppsh      | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:28
unBG1D | judyssi   | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:27
vvkOSd | judyssi   | 2012-01-31    | 17:25:24
```

I wanna calculate time difference in seconds between recent date and previous date.

Can you help me to build MySql query?

Comment: This question has been answered ad nauseum - please check the "Related" column to the right of your screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`recent_date`)
   -
   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`previous_date`)
AS
   `time difference`;
```