# Possible to calculate the time difference between two datetime fields in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between two dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

I have three fields in a table.  Date1, Date2, and DiffinHours.  In our PHP code, when Date2 is set, we calculate the difference in hours between Date2 and Date1 and then set DiffinHours to that value.

However, we have a database where the calculations were not being done for some period of time, and we need to calculate DiffinHours for that time frame.  I can write a script to do it, but am hoping it can be done via a query.

Comment: A quick search through the MySQL date and time functions reveals the TIMESTAMPDIFF() function. Might that work for your situation? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I agree there's many threads on this, but she's looking how to do an `UPDATE` on the difference.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  That link helped as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query periodically. Keep track of the last time the row was evaluated, and check that value for 0 (meaning timediff for the row hasn't been calc'ed yet):

```
UPDATE database SET DiffInHours = HOUR(TIMEDIFF(date2, date1)), lastEval = NOW() WHERE date2 != 0 AND lastEval = 0;
```

Or maybe you mean a one time query to backfill the database, here the query is just run when Diffinhours is zero:

```
UPDATE database SET DiffInHours = HOUR(TIMEDIFF(date2, date1)) WHERE date2 != 0 AND DiffInHours = 0;
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this one because it's closest to what I needed.  I didn't need the lastEval part - just needed to know when date2 wasn't null.  Since it's a one time query - the script will take over for future entries, this did the trick.  Thank you.