# To calculate difference between two datetimes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want the **query** to calculate the difference between two date time fields

- to calculate total time taken
- two date time fields are in same table
  as **start_time and stop_time**
- And I want to calculate total start duration and stop duration

Comment: You need to work on your question, we can't just do the job for you!

Comment: http://www.google.com will answer it for you. Or searching stack overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_get_the_time_difference_between_two_date_columns http://sqlandme.com/2011/05/22/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-tsql/    Show what you have tried so far, IN CODE and we can help out. Otherwise you can pay a programmer to do your work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to convert your datetime expressions to seconds since the UNIX epoch, then taking the sum of all differences will yield the total duration in seconds:

```
SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(stop_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) FROM my_table
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa7c2/1/0).

Note that `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is limited to the range `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2012-12-30 12:01:01','2012-12-31 10:02:00'); 
-- result: 79259  the difference in seconds with the time.
```

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) link for more details on `DateTime` functions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(STOP_TIME - START_TIME) AS INTERVAL
FROM ......
```