# Number of days between two given dates

Tags: sql, hibernate, date, hql

How do I calculate number of days between the to dates strictly using HQL alone.

supposing `Current_Date` and `Expiry_Date` are two dates fetched from database. I want to calculate days between `Current_Date` and `Expiry_Date`.

Also, How will I handle, if any of the value is `null` ?

Comment: try to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured an solution for my issue.

`(extract(doy from  bp.qhrIqamaexpirDate)-extract(doy from now()))`

`doy` represents The day of the year (1 - 365/366).

```
bp.qhrIqamaexpirDate : 2013-02-28 00:00:00.0

now() : 2013-03-14 14:53:12.051562

extract(doy from  bp.qhrIqamaexpirDate) : 59, extract(doy from now()) : 73
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '2013-12-05 12:10:09.3312722';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '2013-12-04 12:10:09.3312722'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, isnull(@startdate,GetDate()), isnull(@enddate,GetDate()));
```