# Subtract date in grails filter (le) in filter grails gorm

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, criteria

I have a column with deadlineDays (integer), i need a filter with column in a grails gorm :

```
def products = Product.withCriteria() {
            createAlias("company", "comp")
            eq("comp.autoProductApproval", true)
            le("statusDate", new Date())
            notExists(subQuery)
            maxResults(100)
        }
```

In le("statusDate"... i need subtract (new Date() - comp.deadlineDays())

How do this in grails gorm?

Comment: Possibly use `HQL` refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403544/number-of-days-between-two-given-dates/15403576#15403576  `SELECT DATEDIFF(day, isnull(@startdate,GetDate()), isnull(@enddate,GetDate()))` where you pass in the two dates and this provides numerical value out of sql

Comment: fixed problem, used : sqlRestriction("status_date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL deadline_days DAY)")