# Reverse of DATE_ADD / INTERVAL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In mysql, we can do the following for adding months:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-08-20', INTERVAL 13 MONTH); //Result: 2015-09-20
```

Is there any way to do the reversed operation ? Example:

```
SELECT DIFF_IN_MONTHS('2015-09-20', '2014-08-20') //Result: 13
```

Roundings due to day differences are not a problem for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) does this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2015-09-20', '2014-08-20');
```

> TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
>
> Returns datetime_expr2 – datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and
>   datetime_expr2 are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be
>   a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime
>   having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for the
>   result (an integer) is given by the unit argument

Answer (score 0):

So you are wanting to get the difference in days between the 2 dates?

```
    DATEDIFF('1015-09-20','2014-08-20')
```