# Calculate Time Diff between different column and row [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, row, calculated-columns

Im trying to calculate the time difference between an user login/logout, to do so, I need to do following operation: 2nd Login - 1st Logout, i don't know even how to explain to correctly so i ll post the table result here to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql

Comment: Try putting sample data and desired results into your question.

Comment: Can you share your table(s)' structure(s) please?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The table is this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz1Nh.jpg the result that i want is the 3rd column "Difference", this should be the result of the SELECT... to obtain the "00:06:38" I did **Login 2nd row** (06/10/2014 14:21) - **logout 1st row** (06/10/2014 14:15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acomplish this by left joining the table with itself. This query renders the table you posted:

```
SELECT t.Login, t.Logout, TIMEDIFF(MIN(t2.Login), t.Logout) AS Difference
FROM my_table t
LEFT JOIN my_table t2
ON t.Logout < t2.Login
GROUP BY t.Logout
```

MIN(t2.Login) is the next login after t.Logout