# MySQL Query Help - DATEDIFF and Writing Results to A New Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so I have an obnoxious problem to solve here and im stumped.

I have a MySQL table with basically this structure

```
id  transdate  startdate   enddate      unit1  unit1price   unit2   unit2price

1   2014-07-31   2014-10-25  2014-10-29   22     25.00        27      25.00
```

What I need to do is create another column that is totaldays which calculates the number of days between startdate and enddate.

How do I do this?

Thanks so much

Comment: If i put `get date difference in MySQL` in Google i get a zillion counts,what have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql

Comment: I get that I need to use DATEDIFF but how do I loop through the rows and write that value to a new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--create the column

```
alter table YourTableName
add column daysdiff int;
```

--update the new column with appropriate computation

```
update YourTableName
set daysdiff = datediff(enddate, startdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
SELECT datediff(enddate, startdate)...
```

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff