# Calculating Date Difference using date() method

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to execute the following piece of code to calculate the difference b/w the dates obtained using the PHP `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` function.

```
$fine = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DATEDIFF(".$query_exec['Date_issued'].", ".$query_exec['Date_returned'].") AS days");
$fine = $fine*10;
```

The value that $fine if returning is only 0 even if the difference b/w the dates is >0.

Plz help, thank you

Comment: show us what in $query_exec

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `$query_exec['Date_issued']` and `$query_exec['Date_returned']` contain something like `2017-03-01`, `2017-03-30` that, when inserted in the SQL code above produces:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(2017-03-30, 2017-03-01) AS DAYS
```

There is no `DATE` value in this SQL. `2017-03-01` and `2017-03-30` are numeric expressions that evaluates to `2013` and `1984`.

Enclose the values of `$query_exec['Date_issued']` and `$query_exec['Date_returned']` in quotes in the SQL:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT DATEDIFF('%s','%s') AS DAYS",
               $query_exec['Date_issued'], $query_exec['Date_returned']);
```

I used [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to make it more readable. You can use strings concatenation as well if you like it more.

Comment: Surely you should use a parameterised query rather than `sprintf` for this.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I tried to solve just the mentioned issue and nothing more. However, if the value of `$query_exec['Date_issued']` is generated using `date()` there is no danger of SQL injection and if it is not executed in a loop, a parametrized query doesn't bring performance improvements.

Comment: I've benn trying what he's suggesting but usign the date() function rather than hard-coded values
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20419537/7744098

Comment: Also there's nothing wrong without enclosing $Date_issued & $ Date_returned into sing quotes as I'm getting both the dates accurately.

Comment: @ParvezKhan you didn't get it. `2017-03-01` is not a date, it's a numeric expression. To be more specific, its value is exactly `2013` (as the result of the operations: `2017-3=2014`, `2014-1=2013`). The query `SELECT DATE_DIFF(2017-03-30, 2017-03-01)` is the same as `SELECT DATE_DIFF(1984, 2013)`

Comment: So how come the output is always 0 & how should I get the current time then in those 2 variables?

Comment: @ParvezKhan take a look at the results of this query: http://rextester.com/live/MTO57069. [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) cannot handle numbers

Comment: Hmm, now I understand, I'll try implementing it in my code & let you know asap :)

Comment: @axiac it's still not working man, I've tried the exact same code you've provided but the output is still 0, help plz