# Select DATEDIFF() AS DAYS using date() method

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I've using the DATEDIFF method to get the difference b/w two dates obtained using the date(YYYY:mm:DD HH:MM:ss) function but getting the output 0 every time, even when the difference is more than 1 day.

here's my code -

```
if(isset($_GET['rt']))
{
$dateis=$_GET['rt'];
}
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE issued_books SET Date_returned = '$date' WHERE Book_id = '$bk_id' AND Date_issued = '$dateis'"))
{
    $fine = sprintf("SELECT DATEDIFF('%s','%s') AS DAYS",
               '$date', '$dateis');
    $fine = $fine*10;
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE member_db SET Fine_amt = (Fine_amt + '$fine') WHERE Member_id = '$mem'");
}
```

any kinda help would be really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: @Tiger I was suggested to do that, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43111907/7744098

Comment: no no error, but I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: the guy, who suggested me the sprintf() solution, used hard-coded values as you can see on that page & it works fine for those values, but not for the ones, I'm getting from the date() function

Answer (score 0):

1.remove single quotes for '$date' and '$dateis'

```
$fine = sprintf("SELECT DATEDIFF('%s','%s') AS DAYS", $date, $dateis);
```

2.`$fine = $fine*10;` // this will not work since query is not yet executed in mysql, that's why you will always get undesired result

And always sanitize your parameters to avoid sql injection

Comment: here's your output - SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-03-27 12:35:04','0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS DAYS

Comment: @ParvezKhan what is the value of $dateis?
> $dateis=$_GET['rt'];

Comment: you should convert to date the value of $dateis
`$dateis = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_GET['rt']);` or check it if it is a validate date

Comment: you can see the value of $dateis as it is getting printed in the output in the same format that you are suggesting.

Comment: take a look at this - http://rextester.com/live/MTO57069

Here the calculation is fine but only for hard-coded values.

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-03-30 10:26:44', '2017-03-29 17:33:18') AS DAYS
When I run the above query in php myadmin, it works fine

but, in php, I'm getting error for the below code;
$fine = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-03-30 10:26:44', '2017-03-29 17:33:18') AS DAYS");
   echo $fine;

Comment: @ParvezKhan what is the error shown?

Comment: it was some mysqli error, like it can't convert the $fine variable to string

Comment: @ParvezKhan can you paste here the mysqli error?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/676828/7744098 using the strtotime() & floor methods.

Thank you all for commenting.