# check dates on database

Tags: php, mysql

On my database table I have 2 columns, start_date and end_date.

Sample data would be:

```
-------------------------------
start_date     |     end_date
-------------------------------
2017-11-01           2017-11-02
2017-11-03           2017-11-07
2017-11-20           2017-11-28
2017-11-13           2017-12-02
-------------------------------
```

I need to find if there are 5 consecutive days that are not yet used, which in this case, there is:

```
(2017-11-08 to 2017-11-13)
```

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two dates in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql)

Comment: @Michel, I'd argue this is not a duplicate, as while it may use that function is the solution, the question is different

Comment: i've tried one similar to Michel's suggestion but really stucked on how to find the dates not used.

Comment: Are you trying to verify that the specified date range works, or that there is a range somewhere that is 5 days, and what it is?

Comment: Do you need to check the consecutive dates for both the columns?

Comment: @kchason trying to find consecutive days that are not occupied/used between the dates.

Comment: ex. nov 1-30, trying to find if there are 5 consecutive days open based on the start and end date

Comment: 3rd to 7th December is also unused

Comment: @Strawberry, isn't that beyond the range shown?

Comment: @kchason You tell me.

Comment: @Strawberry, we might need OP to weigh in, but I would assume given that the last date in the table is 2017-12-02, it'd have to be before that, otherwise, we could say any point in 2018 is fair game, no?

Comment: yeah, was looking for dates between nov 1-30 in my sample

Comment: @kchason i think that's a fair assessment, and likewise any point prior to this week.

Comment: @badboy If it ain't in the question, it ain't in the question.

Comment: Though, to @Strawberry's point, if your first date was the 6th of November, my answer wouldn't identify Nov 1-5 as an acceptable range. It only looks within the range given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to check for edge cases depending on your actual data and if there were no overlap dates, but this is a good start for the provided data.

Assuming table and data as defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE
  `appointments`
 (
     `appointment_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `start_date` DATE,
     `end_date` DATE
 );

INSERT INTO
     `appointments`
 (`start_date`, `end_date`)
 VALUES
 ('2017-11-01', '2017-11-02'),
 ('2017-11-03', '2017-11-07'),
 ('2017-11-20', '2017-11-28'),
 ('2017-11-13', '2017-12-02');
```

If you order the rows, and take the lag from the end date before it, and take any gaps of 5 or more. In SQL Server there are LAG functions, but here's a way of doing the same. Then once you have a table of all rows and their corresponding gaps, you take the start date of that period, and create the gap period from the number of days between. Since `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is inclusive, you need to subtract a day.

```
SET @end_date   = NULL;

SELECT 
   DATE_ADD(`start_date`, INTERVAL -(`gap_from_last`-1) DAY) AS `start_date`,
   `start_date` AS `end_date`
FROM
(
SELECT
    `appointment_id`,
    CASE 
      WHEN @end_date IS NULL THEN NULL
      ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @end_date, `start_date`) 
    END AS `gap_from_last`,
    `start_date`,
    @end_date   := `end_date` AS `end_date`  -- Save the lag date from the row before
FROM
    `appointments`
ORDER BY
    `start_date`,
    `end_date`
) AS `date_gap` -- Build table that has the dates and the number of days between
WHERE
  `gap_from_last` > 5;
```

Provides:

```
start_date | end_date
------------------------
2017-11-08 | 2017-11-13
```

Edit: Oops! Forgot the SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09cfce/16)

Comment: wow, this is exactly what I was looking for! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY unused_start
     , MIN(y.start_date) unused_end 
  FROM appointments x 
  JOIN appointments y 
    ON y.start_date >= x.end_date 
 GROUP 
    BY x.start_date  
HAVING DATEDIFF(MIN(y.start_date),unused_start) >= 5;
```