# error on MySQL when i add month to the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset including a endDate and a startDate:

| endDate | startDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-06-30 |

now I try `datediff(endDate, startDate)` and I get: `149`

when I try `datediff(month,endDate, startDate)` I get error

> 1582 incorrect parameter

what is wrong?

Comment: Hint:  `datediff()` in MySQL takes two arguments, as your first example shows,.

Comment: but docs say I can do DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) and datepart could be month or year, so it takes 3 arguments,....

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) it doesn't show that. Are you sure you're reading MySQL documentation?

Comment: [`timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) allows you to specify the units.

Comment: You're reading the SQL-Server documentation, not MySQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: ok wrong docs :)

Comment: Why is your start date after the end date?

Comment: This is answered in the as part of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759248/difference-between-two-dates-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the syntax from SQL-Server, it doesn't work with MySQL. In MySQL the function that allows you to specify the time units of the result is `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, startDate, endDate)
FROM tablename
```