# Sql query- Get results between two different date columns with its exact days match

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 columns in 'deals' table.
- subscribed_date
- expired_date

I want the **SQL query** that to filter the records with 2 columns difference as follows

> (expired_date - subscribed_date) == 7 days

For eg:

```
id  |  subscribed_date      | expired_date
1   |  2015-07-04 04:13:29  | 2015-09-03 04:13:29
2   |  2015-06-03 04:13:29  | 2015-06-10 04:13:29
3   |  2015-01-05 04:13:29  | 2015-02-08 04:13:29
```

**In the above example, the result should be id=2 because its difference is 7 days.**

Is it possible through SQL query without iterations?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `SELECT * FROM deals WHERE DATEDIFF(expired_date, subscribed_date) = 7`?

Further info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546053/mysql-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-days).

Comment: Thank you polkovnikov.ph :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use `timestampdiff` function

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(day,'2015-06-03 04:13:29','2015-06-10 04:13:29') as d ;
+------+
| d    |
+------+
|    7 |
+------+
```

So the query becomes

```
select * from deals
where timestampdiff(day,subscribed_date,expired_date) = 7
```

Comment: Thank you Abhik for your quick reply! However, polkovnikov.ph approach is easiest one for me. So I chosen his answer as accepted and also I voted up you :)