# Substract datetime to get days and hour in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, left-join, datetime-format

I have a join table, on the table I want to join with the main table there is a datetime column name `delivery_date_to`, I want to substract `delivery_date_to` to current date time and the substraction result will be in days and hour format (example: 2 days 23 hour) as a record. Here's how I join the table,

```
SELECT marketplace_orders.entity_id as id, 
       sales_order.delivery_date_to as delivery_date_to,
       (deliver_date_to - current_time = xx days xx hour) as time_left
FROM marketplace_orders 
INNER JOIN sales_order
      ON sales_order.entity_id = marketplace_orders.order_id
      AND sales_order.status IN ("pending","processing")
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546053/mysql-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-days?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT 
    marketplace_orders.entity_id as id, 
    sales_order.delivery_date_to as delivery_date_to,
    CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Day,deliver_date_to,NOW()), ' days ',
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,deliver_date_to,NOW()),24), ' hour')  as time_left
FROM marketplace_orders 
INNER JOIN sales_order
    ON sales_order.entity_id = marketplace_orders.order_id
       AND sales_order.status IN ("pending","processing")
```

**Demo :**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9283a8/5

Comment: `+` as concatenation operator this works in SQL-server.. In MySQL you need to use `CONCAT()` function

Comment: @RaymondNijland have just edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  ya I forget that I am writing the query in MYSQL thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the help.